# How to call a compute function inside a Onchange() in odoo 10?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

How we can call a computed function inside onchange() in odoo.
For example ! i have two fields  (start_date and end_date).
When change start_date how end_date will automatically changed.

here is my code :

```
@api.onchange('start_date')
def onchange_start_date(self):
    self.update({
       'validity_date': self.compute_next_days()     
     })

def compute_next_days(self, exprdate):
    ten_days = relativedelta(days=10)
    expr_date = fields.Date.from_string(exprdate)
    return fields.Date.to_string(expr_date + ten_days)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `self.compute_next_days()` without `exprdate` argument, and you can update `validity_date` in this way:

```
self.validity_date = self.compute_next_days(self.start_date)
```

Your `onchange` method should be:

```
@api.onchange('start_date')
def onchange_start_date(self):
    self.validity_date = self.compute_next_days(self.start_date)
```

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@api.depends(fields_name)` for this. In your compute method add `@api.depends`and `@api.onchange` both.